# Why `.decode("utf-16")` with ASCII encoded string sometime crash?

Tags: python, decode, utf-16

I wanted to show how we can reduce the number of character required to code a script in Python using encoding conversion, and I took the [Mandelbrot set obfuscated example](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-it-possible-to-write-obfuscated-one-liners-in-python) from the [Python programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#programming-faq) as an example.

```py
code = b"""print((lambda Ru,Ro,Iu,Io,IM,Sx,Sy:reduce(lambda x,y:x+'\n'+y,map(lambda y,
Iu=Iu,Io=Io,Ru=Ru,Ro=Ro,Sy=Sy,L=lambda yc,Iu=Iu,Io=Io,Ru=Ru,Ro=Ro,i=IM,
Sx=Sx,Sy=Sy:reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,map(lambda x,xc=Ru,yc=yc,Ru=Ru,Ro=Ro,
i=i,Sx=Sx,F=lambda xc,yc,x,y,k,f=lambda xc,yc,x,y,k,f:(k<=0)or (x*x+y*y
>=4.0) or 1+f(xc,yc,x*x-y*y+xc,2.0*x*y+yc,k-1,f):f(xc,yc,x,y,k,f):chr(
64+F(Ru+x*(Ro-Ru)/Sx,yc,0,0,i)),range(Sx))):L(Iu+y*(Io-Iu)/Sy),range(Sy
))))(-2.1, 0.7, -1.2, 1.2, 30, 80, 24))"""

shorter_code = code.decode("u16")  # crash here
print(shorter_code)
code_back = shorter_code.encode("u16")[2:]
print(code_back)
print(code_back == code)
```

However, the code crashed unexpectedly during execution.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lancet\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2022.3\scratches\scratch_24.py", line 9, in <module>
    shorter_code = code.decode("u16")
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x29 in position 472: truncated data
```

I already did this kind of tricks for challenges in CodinGame code golf mode with success. So I tried with another example from the documentation, the `First 10 Fibonacci numbers` example, with success.

```py
code = b"""print(list(map(lambda x,f=lambda x,f:(f(x-1,f)+f(x-2,f)) if x>1 else 1:
f(x,f), range(10))))"""

shorter_code = code.decode("u16")
print(shorter_code)
# 牰湩⡴楬瑳洨灡氨浡摢⁡ⱸ㵦慬扭慤砠昬⠺⡦⵸ⰱ⥦昫砨㈭昬⤩椠⁦㹸‱汥敳ㄠ਺⡦ⱸ⥦‬慲杮⡥〱⤩⤩
code_back = shorter_code.encode("u16")[2:]
print(code_back)
# b'print(list(map(lambda x,f=lambda x,f:(f(x-1,f)+f(x-2,f)) if x>1 else 1:\nf(x,f), range(10))))'
print(code_back == code)
# True
```

Why the first string is considered `truncated`?

Comment: So CodinGame counts characters instead of bytes? Madness!

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeah XD It's easy win when you know this trick, at least for long code, because it's not always efficient enough.

Comment: How does that help for Python, though? I get that it could help for those golf languages where single characters mean something, like maybe 'P' means an iterator of the prime numbers. With 65336 different characters they could put a lot more stuff into a single character. But Python? How does that benefit?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. I don't think this "benefit" to python. It's just a tricks to shorten a code you can `exec`.

Comment: Ohh... you decode and exec. Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Even size string required, add trailing white-space to the string

An ASCII character are represented as 8-bit bytes with the most significant bit set to 0. Since `UTF-16` characters are represented as 16-bit bytes, you need an even number of 8-bit bytes to decode it in `UTF-16`. If you don't, the last byte of the string will miss 8-byte of data and considered truncated.

The length of the Mandelbrot code is `473`, and the length of the Fibonacci code is `92`.

To fix the script, you need a string with an even length, so just add a trailing white-space.

```py
code = b"""print((lambda Ru,Ro,Iu,Io,IM,Sx,Sy:reduce(lambda x,y:x+'\n'+y,map(lambda y,
Iu=Iu,Io=Io,Ru=Ru,Ro=Ro,Sy=Sy,L=lambda yc,Iu=Iu,Io=Io,Ru=Ru,Ro=Ro,i=IM,
Sx=Sx,Sy=Sy:reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,map(lambda x,xc=Ru,yc=yc,Ru=Ru,Ro=Ro,
i=i,Sx=Sx,F=lambda xc,yc,x,y,k,f=lambda xc,yc,x,y,k,f:(k<=0)or (x*x+y*y
>=4.0) or 1+f(xc,yc,x*x-y*y+xc,2.0*x*y+yc,k-1,f):f(xc,yc,x,y,k,f):chr(
64+F(Ru+x*(Ro-Ru)/Sx,yc,0,0,i)),range(Sx))):L(Iu+y*(Io-Iu)/Sy),range(Sy
))))(-2.1, 0.7, -1.2, 1.2, 30, 80, 24)) """

print(len(code))
# 474
shorter_code = code.decode("u16")
print(shorter_code)
# 牰湩⡴氨浡摢⁡畒刬Ɐ畉䤬Ɐ䵉匬ⱸ祓爺摥捵⡥慬扭慤砠礬砺✫✊礫洬灡氨浡摢⁡ⱹ䤊㵵畉䤬㵯潉刬㵵畒刬㵯潒匬㵹祓䰬氽浡摢⁡捹䤬㵵畉䤬㵯潉刬㵵畒刬㵯潒椬䤽ⱍ匊㵸硓匬㵹祓爺摥捵⡥慬扭慤砠礬砺礫洬灡氨浡摢⁡ⱸ捸刽Ⱶ捹礽Ᵽ畒刽Ⱶ潒刽Ɐ椊椽匬㵸硓䘬氽浡摢⁡捸礬ⱣⱸⱹⱫ㵦慬扭慤砠Ᵽ捹砬礬欬昬⠺㱫〽漩⁲砨砪礫礪㸊㐽〮 牯ㄠ昫砨Ᵽ捹砬砪礭礪砫Ᵽ⸲⨰⩸⭹捹欬ㄭ昬㨩⡦捸礬ⱣⱸⱹⱫ⥦挺牨ਨ㐶䘫刨⭵⩸刨ⵯ畒⼩硓礬Ᵽⰰⰰ⥩Ⱙ慲杮⡥硓⤩㨩⡌畉礫⠪潉䤭⥵匯⥹爬湡敧匨੹⤩⤩⴨⸲ⰱ〠㜮‬ㄭ㈮‬⸱ⰲ㌠ⰰ㠠ⰰ㈠⤴ 
code_back = shorter_code.encode("u16")[2:]
print(code_back)
b"print((lambda Ru,Ro,Iu,Io,IM,Sx,Sy:reduce(lambda x,y:x+'\n'+y,map(lambda y,\nIu=Iu,Io=Io,Ru=Ru,Ro=Ro,Sy=Sy,L=lambda yc,Iu=Iu,Io=Io,Ru=Ru,Ro=Ro,i=IM,\nSx=Sx,Sy=Sy:reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,map(lambda x,xc=Ru,yc=yc,Ru=Ru,Ro=Ro,\ni=i,Sx=Sx,F=lambda xc,yc,x,y,k,f=lambda xc,yc,x,y,k,f:(k<=0)or (x*x+y*y\n>=4.0) or 1+f(xc,yc,x*x-y*y+xc,2.0*x*y+yc,k-1,f):f(xc,yc,x,y,k,f):chr(\n64+F(Ru+x*(Ro-Ru)/Sx,yc,0,0,i)),range(Sx))):L(Iu+y*(Io-Iu)/Sy),range(Sy\n))))(-2.1, 0.7, -1.2, 1.2, 30, 80, 24)) "
print(code_back == code)
# True
```